# onMapReady executa mais rápido que a função que recupera a localização

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

olá, estou tentando utilizar ajuda de mapas em meu aplicativo. Eu recupero as coordenadas através de Json, o problema é que a função que leva até a coordenada (onMapReady) executa mais rápido que a função que recupera as coordenadas.

public class LocalizacaoFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private Empresa mEmpresa;
private static GoogleMap mMap;
private static SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
private static String empresa;
private static String endereco;
private static String bairro;
private static String cidade;
private static String estado;
private static String latitude;
private static String longitude;
double dLatitude;
double dLongitude;
private String urlEmpresa;

private boolean chamou = false;

LocationManager lm;

private static View rootView;

public LocalizacaoFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.localizacao_fragment, container, false);

        supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager != null) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } catch (InflateException e) {
    }

    return rootView;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    double dLatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
    double dLongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng localizacao = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localizacao).title(empresa).snippet(endereco + " - " + bairro + " - " + cidade + "/" + estado)).showInfoWindow();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(localizacao));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(localizacao, 16));

}


private void recuperarEndereco() {
    chamou = true;
    JsonArrayRequest recuperarLocalizacao = new JsonArrayRequest(urlEmpresa,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            mEmpresa = new Empresa();

                            empresa = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("empresa"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            endereco = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("endereco"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            bairro = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("bairro"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            cidade = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("cidade"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            estado = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("estado"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            latitude = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("latitude"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                            longitude = URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("longitude"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8");


                            dLatitude = Double.parseDouble(latitude);
                            dLongitude = Double.parseDouble(longitude);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(recuperarLocalizacao);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
    Bundle params = intent.getExtras();
    if (params != null) {
        urlEmpresa = params.getString("urlEmpresa");
    }
    recuperarEndereco();
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}
```

}

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei uma solução, não sei se é a mais correta mais funcionou para mim.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    recuperarEndereco();
}

private void recuperarEndereco() {
    JsonArrayRequest recuperarLocalizacao = new JsonArrayRequest(urlEmpresa,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            mEmpresa = new Empresa();

                            mEmpresa.setEmpresa(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("empresa"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setEndereco(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("endereco"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setBairro(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("bairro"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setCidade(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("cidade"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setEstado(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("estado"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setLatitude(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("latitude"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                            mEmpresa.setLongitude(URLDecoder.decode(
                                    URLEncoder.encode(obj.getString("longitude"), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"));

                            double dLatitude = Double.parseDouble(mEmpresa.getLatitude());
                            double dLongitude = Double.parseDouble(mEmpresa.getLongitude());

                            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                            LatLng localizacao = new LatLng(dLatitude, dLongitude);
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(localizacao).title(mEmpresa.getEmpresa()).
                                    snippet(mEmpresa.getEndereco() + " - " + mEmpresa.getBairro() + " - " + mEmpresa.getCidade() + "/" + mEmpresa.getEstado())).showInfoWindow();
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(localizacao));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(localizacao, 16));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    mEmpresa = new Empresa();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(recuperarLocalizacao);
    chamou = true;
}
```